# SCSS changes display: flex; to display: grid;

Tags: sass, flexbox, grid, internet-explorer-11

I am making an internal website for a company.

We have to use Internet explorer.

I am using SCSS to make this work.

This works well in most cases except when I want to use flexbox

SCSS changes

```
.container{
    display: flex;
}
```

to

```
.container{
    display: grid;
}
```

How can I tell it to stop that?

Comment: Do you mean after rendering, the SCSS style will be changed? Try to clear the browser cache and cookie, and check whether it works. Besides, if still not working, try to directly using the CSS format to add style, instead of using the SCSS format.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of internet explorer are you using?

**Internet Explorer 6-9** do not support flexbox at all.

**Internet Explorer 10** supports 2012 syntax for flexbox. So to get this to work cross browser for IE11 and other browsers you could do something like:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  display: flexbox;
}
```

Browsers that do not support the 2012 syntax should ignore the 'flexbox' value however if IE10 encounters it, it should use that.

**Internet Explorer 11** supports the current way of using flexbox. So if you are using IE11 and encountering this issue I would double check that your CSS isn't getting overridden unexpectedly.

**EDIT**

Just saw that you had tagged this as IE11 - I would double check that your values aren't being overriden somewhere. Flex is known to be buggy with IE11 but I can't imagine it would choose to switch to grid unless it was getting that value from a CSS file.